# Compiler warnings C4691 when referencing NuGet package in C++/CLR project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface, warnings

I have the following situation within Visual Studio 2017:

A C++ project which is compiled with the /clr (Common Language Runtime Support switch) has a depedency to Microsoft.Practices.Unity, since we use the IUnityContainer therein. However, several warnings arise in the cpp-File where the reference is made:

```
using namespace Microsoft::Practices::Unity;
```

The warnings after build:

```
warning C4691: 'System::Object': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
warning C4691: 'System::IDisposable': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::IUnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
warning C4691: 'System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::IUnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
warning C4691: 'System::ParamArrayAttribute': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::IUnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
warning C4691: 'System::Type': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::IUnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
warning C4691: 'System::EventHandler': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
warning C4691: 'System::Collections::Generic::IDictionary': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
warning C4691: 'System::Collections::Generic::List': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Collections', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
warning C4691: 'System::Action': type referenced was expected in unreferenced assembly 'System.Runtime', type defined in current translation unit used instead
note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer ' from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.
```

I already found the following topics on several places, which seem to somehow address this issue, but unfortunately without any fix that helped in my case.

- https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/734
- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1781
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/158463/c4691-warnings-with-ccli-nuget.html

Has anyone already found a solution to avoid this warning, apart from deactivating it by #pragma?

---

***Amendment***:
The problem is simply reproducible by creating a new CLR Console Application project within Visual Studio 2017, add a reference to the Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll (Version 4.0.1, from the net45 folder of the NuGet packages) and the following snippet:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
  Microsoft::Practices::Unity::IUnityContainer^ unityContainer = gcnew Microsoft::Practices::Unity::UnityContainer();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by updating the NuGet package of Unity. The old Unity package did only contain dlls up to version 4.5, while in the project version 4.6.2 was set up.

By updating the unity package to the newest version (currently 5.8.2, which is compatible with .net framework up to 4.7), the warnings disappeared completely!